# Avoid passing undefined for optional parameters

Tags: typescript, parameters, undefined

If I have a constructor that has `n` optional parameters and I want to pass a value for only the *last* optional parameter, I have to pass `undefined` `n-1` times.

For example:

```
class House() {
    constructor(door?, roof?, windows?) { }
}
```

If I want to instantiate a new `House` that doesn't have a `door` or a `roof` but does have `windows`, I have to pass `undefined` twice to the constructor:

```
let myHouse = new House(undefined, undefined, new Windows());
```

C# has [named parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), which would be ideal here.

How can I avoid passing `undefined` `n-1` times in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most commonly used approach to this are parameter objects. Instead of using three parameters, you'd use one parameter:

```
interface HouseOptions {
    door?: Door;
    roof?: Roof;
    windows?: Windows;
}

class House() {
    constructor(options: HouseOptions) {...}
}
```

Now you can create a house like this: `new House({windows: new Windows()})`

This is even more flexible than named parameters: Consider the case where you want to allow Houses that have Windows and a Door OR have Windows and a Roof, but not houses that only have a roof. For this scenario, you can do something like this:

```
interface DoorlessHouseOptions {
    roof: Roof;
    windows: Windows;
}

interface RooflessHouseOptions {
    door: Door;
    windows: Windows;
}

class House() {
    constructor(options: DoorlessHouseOptions | RooflessHouseOptions) {...}
}
```

This enforces, that your house either has a door or a roof (along with Windows), in a type safe way, which would be complicated with named parameters. In some languages this could be solved by method overloading, but since Javascript does not allow method overloading, options-objects are usually the way to go.

Another, less commonly used approach would be the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than take multiple parameters, take a single options object parameter.

```
interface HouseOptions {
    door?: any;
    roof?: any;
    windows?: any;
}

class House() {
    constructor(options: HouseOptions ) {
        if(options.door) { ... }
        if(options.roof) { ... }
        if(options.windows) { ... }
    }
}

let house = new House({ windows: new Windows() });
```